# How to create a pfx instead of an snk key

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, signing

I have an old 2010 vb.net project that is signed using a `.pfx` file. What I didn't realise is that my new gitignore has a rule to ignore `*.pfx` files. Now I am at another machine to develop some additional features and my clone of the project's repository has left me unable to build due to lack of a key.

On this machine I have Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition. I am trying to create a new key to replace the old one locally. However, when I try to create new signature file in the `signing` section of the project properties it always create a `.snk` file.

I don't do desktop development much and have forgotten really what the signing thing is all about! I think I only added it before to allow me to publish so that I could build an executable (There were a lot less hoops to jump through in VS6 just to get an executable!).

I was hoping to use the same file type and names for the signing file so there is a minimum of fuss anytime I have to switch development machines again.
Is it possible for me to make VS 2015 CE generate and use a `.pfx` signature file instead of a `.snk`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiddled around for a short while and found that I can use the `Create Test Certificate` button on the same signing section to create a `.pfx` file and then select that. I just made sure the name suited my project et voilà c'est tout!